# The meaning of "consider" in this paragraph?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Newborns come into this world believing that they are the center of it, because they really are the center of their own world. Then social conditioning kicks in, and they learn that the world is full of other people and that they are no better than anyone else. **They are told not to consider only themselves**, and since they are told this so many times, they end up putting themselves last; hence, their natural self-esteem is worn down day by day.

I've searched on oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com and find that "consider" means "to think about something carefully, especially in order to make a decision" or "o think of somebody/something in a particular way", but I think both meaning is not true meaning of "consider" in the sentence, so I guess "consider" mean "make a judgement", and  "They are told not to consider only themselves" means "They are told judge only themselves", right? Can you help me to explain the meaning of it?

Comment: No. I think you should not think the sentence too seriously. "consider" means "think of", and the sentence means that "children are taught not to think only of themselves"

Comment: It means "to take into account as a factor when deciding something or taking some action."  Don't drive your car like a race-car near a playground. Consider the children.

Comment: Consider the impact upon the environment before dumping toxic waste into a river.

Answer (score 1):

Here the sentence refers to the thinking of a new born child. As he grows up he knows he not the only one who is good there are so many competitor.They are told that they are not only special or center of attraction for everyone. There are so many's.

Comment: i think it helped someone